# Adding and Removing Event Listeners Dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I am having issues dynamically adding and removing eventListeners. I want to be able to add an event listener to all child nodes of an element. Then at a later time remove them, and add them back.

*Note: I am aware of EventListener options.once however this doesn't exactly solve my case.*

Here is some sample code of what I am trying to do:

```
var cont;

window.onload = function() {
  cont = document.querySelector(".container");
  [...cont.children].forEach(c => {
    c.addEventListener("click", clicked.bind(c))
  });
}

function clicked() {
  console.log(`removing event listener from ${this}`);
  this.removeEventListener("click", clicked); //Not actually removing - why?
}
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `.bind` creates a *new* function. The function passed to `addEventListener` can only be removed if *that exact same function* is passed to `removeEventListener`. A bound function is not the same as the original unbound function, so `removeEventListener` won't work if you pass it the unbound function.

In your situation, one possibility would be to use a `Map` indexed by the HTML elements, whose value is the bound listener for that element, so that they can then be removed later:

```js
const listenerMap = new Map();
const cont = document.querySelector(".container");

[...cont.children].forEach(c => {
  const listener = clicked.bind(c);
  listenerMap.set(c, listener);
  c.addEventListener("click", listener);
});

function clicked() {
  console.log(`removing event listener from ${this}`);
  this.removeEventListener("click", listenerMap.get(this));
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>one</div>
  <div>two</div>
  <div>three</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah this makes a lot of sense now. I also realize in my example the object I was binding was redundant however in my real code I am binding multiple things (one of them being the index of that child node). Thanks for the response!